# PostGIS - step in state load (loader_load_staged_data) is producing more columns in select than in insert

Tags: postgis

The loader_load_staged_data function, called from the script generated for states by Loader_Generate_Script, is failing when attempting to insert faces data. The uace20 column is present in the select but not in the insert. Is this a known issue / is there a workaround?

This is PostGIS 3.3.2 on PostgreSQL 15 (Ubuntu 23.04).

```
${PSQL} -c "SELECT loader_load_staged_data(lower(NY_faces), lower(NY_faces));"

NOTICE:  INSERT INTO tiger_data.ny_faces(aiannhce,aiannhfp,anrcfp,atotal,blkgrpce,blkgrpce20,blockce20,cbsafp,cd111fp,cnectafp,comptyp,conctyfp,countyfp,countyfp20,cousubfp,csafp,elsdlea,intptlat,intptlon,lwflag,metdivfp,nctadvfp,nectafp,"offset",placefp,scsdlea,sldlst,sldust,statefp,statefp20,submcdfp,tblkgpce,tfid,the_geom,tractce,tractce20,trsubce,trsubfp,ttractce,unsdlea,zcta5ce) SELECT aiannhce,aiannhfp,anrcfp,atotal,blkgrpce,blkgrpce20,blockce20,cbsafp,cd118fp,cnectafp,comptyp,conctyfp,countyfp,countyfp20,cousubfp,csafp,elsdlea,intptlat,intptlon,lwflag,metdivfp,nctadvfp,nectafp,"offset",placefp,scsdlea,sldlst,sldust,statefp,statefp20,submcdfp,tblkgpce,tfid,the_geom,tractce,tractce20,trsubce,trsubfp,ttractce,uace20,unsdlea,zcta5ce20 FROM tiger_staging.ny_faces;
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 1: ...tractce20,trsubce,trsubfp,ttractce,uace20,unsdlea,zcta5ce20 ...
```

Update with requested info:

```
staging=> SELECT extversion FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'postgis_tiger_geocoder';

 extversion 
------------
 3.3.2
(1 row)

staging=> SELECT website_root from tiger.loader_variables;

                website_root                 
---------------------------------------------
 https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2022
(1 row)
```

(Note - I originally thought this was 3.4, due to a difference between my local env and the cloud env I'm running this on. 3.4.0 appears to work against 2022. Doing more experiments.)

(Note2 - 3.3.2 appears to have fixed the first issue I ran into, but has a subsequent error about some column type, which I can capture later on. 3.4.0 appears to work well against 2022.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your existing install, since you are running 2022, this should be sufficient

```
UPDATE loader_lookuptables SET columns_exclude = 
'{gid,geoid,cpi,suffix1ce,statefp00,statefp10,countyfp00,countyfp10,tractce00,tractce10,blkgrpce00,blkgrpce10,blockce00,blockce10,cousubfp00,submcdfp00,conctyfp00,placefp00,aiannhfp00,aiannhce00,comptyp00,trsubfp00,trsubce00,anrcfp00,elsdlea00,scsdlea00,unsdlea00,uace00,cd108fp,sldust00,sldlst00,vtdst00,zcta5ce00,tazce00,ugace00,puma5ce00,vtdst10,tazce10,uace10,puma5ce10,tazce,uace,vtdst,zcta5ce10,puma5ce,ugace10,pumace10,estatefp,ugace,blockce,pumace20,sdadmlea,uace20}'::text[]
WHERE lookup_name = 'faces';
```

Check what these items read:

SELECT extversion FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'postgis_tiger_geocoder';

SELECT website_root from tiger.loader_variables;

I made a number of corrections to the loader over the past couple of months, but the census changed things a couple of times.  One went into version 3.4.1, but version 3.4.0 at the moment is broken because of tiger census structure changes.

If you want to use https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2023/

Then you'll need changes that haven't been released yet which I have noted in this ticket - https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5642

Comment: Thanks Regina, I updated the post with the info. Do you think upgrading to 3.4.1 will fix it? I'm using the Ubuntu PPA http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt under the lunar distro, and I don't believe they have 3.4.1 published yet, so I'm not sure how I'd go about upgrading.

Comment: Well if you want to stick with loading TIGER2022, the fix is simple as discussed here https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5388  .  I'll edit my answer or give a new answer in a bit.